# Java - groupingBy with collectingAndThen - Is there a faster / better / cleaner way?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, grouping, collectors

I have the following class (with getters):

```
public class AlgorithmPrediction {
    private final String algorithmName;
    private final Map<BaseDatabaseProduct, Double> productsToAccuracy;
}
```

Now I want to create a map from a set filled by `AlgorithmPrediction` objects with the `algorithmName` **(unique)** as key and `productsToAccuracy` as value. I couldn't come up with anything less complex than this:

```
algorithmPredictions.stream()
.collect(
        groupingBy(
                AlgorithmPrediction::getAlgorithmName,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        toSet(),
                        s -> s.stream().map(AlgorithmPrediction::getProductsToAccuracy).collect(toSet())
                )
        )
);
```

This can't be right. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Presumably you can guarantee that `algorithmName` is unique? Otherwise your obtained map will lose some of the information in the initial set.

Comment: @Oly'Oil'Sourbut Forgot to mention that it is unique. I updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: Note that even with non-unique keys and using `groupingBy` you can do it much simpler: [`.
        collect(groupingBy(AlgorithmPrediction::getAlgorithmName,
                    mapping(AlgorithmPrediction::getProductsToAccuracy, toSet())));`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
algorithmPredictions.stream()
                    .collect(toMap(AlgorithmPrediction::getAlgorithmName, 
                                   AlgorithmPrediction::getProductsToAccuracy));
```

Comment: Thank you. Was blind not to see that.

Answer (score 5):

If I've understood you correctly, couldn't you use [`Collectors.toMap(Function<> keyMapper, Function<> valueMapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector, like the following:

```
Map<String, Map<BaseDatabaseProduct, Double>> result = algorithmPredictions.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                AlgorithmPrediction::getAlgorithmName,
                AlgorithmPrediction::getProductsToAccuracy));
```

Comment: @JulianLiebl No worries :-) Glad you're sorted!